# AWS SNS text message publishing not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I'm trying to send an SMS(Text message) to a specific mobile number(IN : India, FROM : India) from the AWS management console. I have tried several times, from several regions but none of the messages has been delivered but it shows

> SMS message published to phone number +91xxxxx successfully.

but the delivery statistics show that the messages have been failed.

Note: I'm using a root user account.

I'm new to AWS.

Any help will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

there are special requirements when sending messages to recipients in India. Verify if you are using message type as `Transactional`. Because `Promotional` might be blocked on default settings.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-senderid-india.html

you will need to adhere to it before using AWS SNS in India.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply but i tried both transactional and promotional but both are not working.